# Implement the same property to different existing classes in swift

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

In my project I have different UI representations of the same model object : my entity can be represented as a table section header (`UITableViewHeaderFooterView`), table cell (`UITableViewCell`), collection section header (`UICollectionReusableView`) or a collection cell (`UICollectionViewCell`).

This representations have separate views (`.xib`) but they present the same object with the same behavior (UI bindings, actions, ...). For now i have a class by view (`UITableViewHeaderFooterView` + `UITableViewCell` + `UICollectionReusableView` + `UICollectionViewCell`) but i have a lot of common code to all classes.

I wonder how to gather this common behaviors in a one class in order to manage all my representations with the same class. I created a class (herited from `UIView`) with the common behavior but i can't use it in my Table/Collection classes since multiple inheritance is not possible.

Comment: Can you shows us with pictures what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Try to create one UIView and do all setup code in it.
For each type (UITableViewCell, HeaderFooterView) create a subclass and add your view as subview to it.